# Convert LOCAL TIME data type value to UTC time

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, datetime, utc

I am trying to write a query that returns records that fall between two dates (each with a cutoff in TIME format). So far I have the following:

For example:

```
SELECT 
T.CustomerName,
T.MoneyToTransfer
FROM dbo.[Transfer] T
WHERE T.CreatedDate BETWEEN '2016-05-10 03:00:00.0000000' AND '2016-05-11 03:00:00.0000000'
```

However the cutoff time 03:00:00.0000000 is only a placeholder for how I think the query needs to be formatted - the TIME needs to be retrieved from another table 'TransferSubscriber' from field 'Cutoff' stored as data type TIME. The problem is that this Cutoff field in table TransferSubscriber is stored in LOCAL time (in a TIME data type). I need to convert this TIME to UTC, and place it in my BETWEEN statement in the TIME part of the comparison (where the 03:00:00.0000000).

I have written the following, which has issues concatenating the date and time variables into one:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, '2016-07-13', 110))

DECLARE @Cutoff AS TIME(7) = (SELECT TOP 1 S.CutoffTime FROM Subscriber.dbo.TransferSubscriber S WHERE ID = 10)

DECLARE @CutoffUTC TIME = (SELECT DATEADD(second,DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), @Cutoff))

DECLARE @StartDateFinal = @startDate + @CutoffUTC
```

@StartDateFinal throws error:

"Operand data type date is invalid for add operator."

I am sure there is a better way to convert local TIME to UTC time, and use it to compare two DATETIME fields.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, '2016-07-13', 110))

DECLARE @Cutoff AS TIME(7) = (SELECT TOP 1 S.CutoffTime FROM Subscriber.dbo.TransferSubscriber S WHERE ID = 10)

DECLARE @CutoffUTC TIME = (SELECT DATEADD(second,DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), @Cutoff))

DECLARE @StartDateFinal DATETIME2

SELECT @StartDateFinal=CAST(CAST(@startDate AS VARCHAR) +' '+ CAST(@CutoffUTC AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME2)

SELECT @StartDateFinal
```

Hope it helps.